# Is this a good approach to solving Atari's "Montezuma's Revenge"?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, deep-rl, hindsight-experience-replay, random-network-distillation

I'm new to Reinforcement Learning. For an internship, I am currently training Atari's "Montezuma's Revenge" using a double Deep Q-Network with [Hindsight Experience Replay (HER)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01495.pdf) (see also [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/reinforcement-learning-with-hindsight-experience-replay-1fee5704f2f8)).

HER is supposed to alleviate the reward sparseness problem. But since the reward is annoyingly too sparse, I have also added a [Random Network Distillation (RND)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.12894.pdf) (see also [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/reinforcement-learning-with-exploration-by-random-network-distillation-a3e412004402)) to encourage the agent to explore new states, by giving it a higher reward when it reaches a previously undiscovered state and a lower reward when it reaches a state it has previously visited multiple times. This is the intrinsic reward I add to the extrinsic reward the game itself gives. I have also used a decaying greedy epsilon policy.

How well should this approach work? Because I've set it to run for 10,000 episodes, and the simulation is quite slow, because of the mini-batch gradient descent step in HER. There are multiple hyperparameters here. Before implementing RND, I considered shaping the reward, but that is just impractical in this case. What can I expect from my current approach? OpenAI's paper on RND cites brilliant results with RND on Montezuma's Revenge. But they obviously used PPO.